# Mahout recommend output only key value

Tags: hadoop2, mahout, mahout-recommender, bigdata

I making recommend item by mahout i see example they alway have a output like this

```
1    [234:5.0,347:5.0,237:5.0,47:5.0,282:5.0,275:5.0,88:5.0,515:5.0,514:5.0,121:5.0]
    2    [282:5.0,210:5.0,237:5.0,234:5.0,347:5.0,121:5.0,258:5.0,515:5.0,462:5.0,79:5.0]
    3    [284:5.0,285:4.828125,508:4.7543354,845:4.75,319:4.705128,124:4.7045455,150:4.6938777,311:4.6769233,248:4.65625,272:4.649266] 
    4    [690:5.0,12:5.0,234:5.0,275:5.0,121:5.0,255:5.0,237:5.0,895:5.0,282:5.0,117:5.0]
```

but my output

```
Key: 1: Value: 1
Key: 2: Value: 2
Key: 3: Value: 3
Key: 4: Value: 4
Key: 5: Value: 5
Key: 6: Value: 6
Key: 7: Value: 7
Key: 8: Value: 8
Key: 9: Value: 9
```

can anyone tell me why then have some solution?
im using Mahout 0.13.0

this is my input

```
10,11,10
10,22,10
10,44,8
20,22,7
20,33,9
20,66,10
20,77,10
20,88,1
30,33,5
30,44,10
30,11,2
30,22,9
40,22,6
40,33,9
40,55,10
40,66,9
40,99,2
40,88,4
```

Comment: Are you using the Hadoop Mapreduce recommenders or the new Spark Itemsimilarity?

Comment: i see the problem is it cant call jobhistory server make mapreduce not run all job of mahout .